# How to validate error message before update in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got the error message before save. But I can't validate the error messages before update.

```
      def create
        # @student = Student.new
        @student = Student.new(student_params)
        
        # @student = @student.school.build(student_params)
        if @student.valid?
          @student.save
            redirect_to students_path
            # render 'new'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
      end
    
      def edit
        @schools = School.all
        @student = Student.find(params[:id])
      end
    
      def update
        @student = Student.find(params[:id])
         if @student.valid?
          @student.update(student_params)
            redirect_to students_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:status, :email, :password, :school_id, :department_id)
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign new attributes to `@student` before you validate:

```
  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.attributes = student_params
    if @student.valid?
      # ... do stuff with valid @student ...
      if @student.save
        redirect_to students_path
      else # when saving failed
        render 'edit'
      end
    else # when @student invalid
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of doing `@student.valid?` you can directly call the `update`. The update will return false in case of validation errors.

```
def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])

    if @student.update(student_params)
        redirect_to students_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I want to do more function before update if @student no have error

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`assign_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) like this:

```
def update
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @student.assign_attributes(student_params)      

  if @student.valid?
    # additional code here
    @student.save
    redirect_to students_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```